# The simpliest way to create pandas_udf finction with two string arguments

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I need to to do certain calculations over strings based on two columns using `pandas_udf`.

My code is as follows:

```
@pandas_udf(BooleanType())
def is_one_pd(ser: pd.Series, ser2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
  def is_one(s):
    return (re.search("1", s.title) is not None) & (re.search("1", s.comp_short) is not None)

  df = pd.DataFrame({'title':ser, 'comp_short':ser2})
  return df.apply(is_one, 1)

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([("1", "1"), ("2", "2"), ("3", "3")], columns=["title", "comp_short"]))
df.select(is_one_pd(df.title, df.comp_short)).show()
```

It looks too complicated. Is there any better option? I need to use pandas_udf because the real example is more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly apply the regex search on the series without constructing dataframes:

```
import re 
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
import pandas as pd

@pandas_udf(BooleanType())
def is_one_pd(ser: pd.Series, ser2: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return (ser.apply(lambda s: re.search("1", s) is not None) & 
            ser2.apply(lambda s: re.search("1", s) is not None))

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([("1", "1"), ("2", "2"), ("3", "3")], columns=["title", "comp_short"]))
df.select(is_one_pd(df.title, df.comp_short)).show()
```

Comment: thanks. My real example is more complicated and I can not use lambdas. Is my approach correct in this case ?

Comment: If you can't use lambdas, you can put the regex search in a function and apply to the series separately, then combine with `&`